# Firefox, show link URLs in status bar?

Tags: firefox, user-interface

For web browsing I use [**Pale Moon**](http://www.palemoon.org). Pale Moon has a **Status Bar**, similar to what is now known as the **Add-on Bar** in Firefox.

With Pale Moon when I hover over a link

- URL is shown in the status bar
- URL is shown instantly
- Entire width of status bar is allowed for URL, if necessary

With Firefox when I hover over a link

- URL is shown in a tooltip in lower left corner
- URL is shown after intentional delay
- Only half the browser window width is allowed for URL

Is there a way to make Firefox behave more like Pale Moon? I realize **Status-4-Evar** might be the best solution here but I wish to see what, if any other options are out there. I will also accept **well thought out and referenced** answers as to why the Firefox way is "better".

Answer (score 6):

Going in the same order as above...

### Show the URL over the Add-on Bar:

1. Using [Stylish](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [userChrome.css](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss), define the following CSS:

   ```
   statuspanel
   {
       z-index: 1 !important;
       bottom: 1px !important;
   }

   toolbar#addon-bar
   {
       z-index: 0 !important;
   }
   ```

   [image: before]

With some extra tweaking, the final result can look like this (Windows 7):

[image: after]

```
label.statuspanel-label
{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: #cedaeb !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

### Remove the delay and transition:

1. Set the `browser.overlink-delay` preference in `about:config` to **0**. Restart Firefox.
2. Define the following CSS:

   ```
   statuspanel[type=overLink], statuspanel[inactive][previoustype=overLink]
   {
       -moz-transition: none !important;
   }
   ```

### Allow URLs to span the whole width of the window:

1. Define the following CSS:

   ```
   statuspanel
   {
       max-width: 100% !important;
   }
   ```

### Bonus:

If you are going to use the Add-on Bar as a permanent fixture, you can hide it's close button with:

```
toolbarbutton#addonbar-closebutton
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

---

### Copy & Paste

Here is the combined CSS, sans Windows 7 theme:

```
statuspanel
{
    z-index: 1 !important;
    bottom: 1px !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

toolbar#addon-bar
{
    z-index: 0 !important;
}

statuspanel[type=overLink], statuspanel[inactive][previoustype=overLink]
{
    -moz-transition: none !important;
}

toolbarbutton#addonbar-closebutton
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I've combined the CSS to make it easier to apply. If you are still having problems, copy and paste this block of code.

Comment: Are you using Stylish or the userChrome approach?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. My CSS works on a new profile, if I use Stylish or userChrome. Can you fire up a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Managing-profiles), and see if the fade still remains? I am using Firefox 12.0

Comment: Ok. I'm out of time tonight, but tomorrow I will post directions for how I got the CSS selectors in the first place. Perhaps our Firefoxes are slightly different.

Comment: I noticed its not actually a fade out, but a delay before disappearing. With Pale Moon it is instant appear/disappear.